# Eclipse 4.5.1. (MARS.1) Method not found: setDefaultEditor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a plugin that used to work with Eclipse Indigo, Kepler,Luna and Mars (4.5). It supports the Frege programming language (http://www.frege-lang.org/fregide/). It is based on the IMP framework, which is, unfortunately, not maintained anymore (and I don't have the source code).

Tonight I checked for updates, and it found Eclipse 4.5.1.
After updating, eclipse had a fancy new splash screen that says "MARS.1".

Yet it can't initialize the plugin anymore!

In the Error Log, I get the message:

```
Plug-in "frege.ide" was unable to instantiate class "frege.imp.builders.FregeBuilder".
```

and the stack trace seems to indicate that some method has vanished from the Eclipse API:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.FileEditorMapping.setDefaultEditor(Lorg/eclipse/ui/internal/registry/EditorDescriptor;)V
    at org.eclipse.imp.language.LanguageRegistry.addUniversalEditorMappings(LanguageRegistry.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.imp.language.LanguageRegistry.initializeRegistryAsNeeded(LanguageRegistry.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.imp.language.LanguageRegistry.findLanguage(LanguageRegistry.java:206)
    at frege.imp.builders.FregeBuilderBase.<clinit> (FregeBuilderBase.java:53)
    ...
```

Here are my questions:

1. Does anybody know why this method is gone?
2. How can I restrict installation of my plugin to LUNA, KEPLER and INDIGO only?
3. Would it be possible to supply a fake setDefaultEditor method that does whatever must be done now to register the Editor for the plugin?

Comment: Why are you call `FileEditorMapping` directly? It is an **internal** class and is therefore not part of the Eclipse API and can be changed at any time.

Comment: @greg-449 I don't. It is the IMP plugin framework that does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setDefaultEditor` method does still exist in `FileEditorMapping` but it now takes an `IEditorDescriptor` argument instead of `EditorDescriptor`. This will cause the `NoSuchMethodError`. Since this class is an internal class and therefore not part of the API this is a valid change.

According to the [IMP Wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/IMP) the IMP project has moved to a [github project](https://github.com/impulse-org), you may be able to get up to date code from there (or at least get the source).

Comment: So all that would be needed would be to re-compile the IMP stuff? Since, certainly, an EditorDescription **is an** IEditorDescription, or at least I hope so.

Comment: Yes I think recompiling would be OK.

Comment: Was able to fix it switching to successor of IMP - thank you for the link, @greg-449